# Output the simplified Goodstein sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

A number is in base-b simplified Goodstein form if it is written as

```
b + b + ... + b + c,   0 < c ≤ b
```

The simplified Goodstein sequence of a number starts with writing the number in base-1 simplified Goodstein form, then replacing all 1's with 2's and subtracting 1. Rewrite the result in base-2 simplified Goodstein form, then replace all 2's with 3's and subtract 1, etc. until you reach 0.

Your program is to take a positive integer input and output/print its Goodstein sequence and terminate. Your program should handle numbers less than 100, though it may not terminate in a reasonable amount of time.

For example, given 3 as the input, your program should output (the right side is just explanation)

```
1 + 1 + 1                | 3 = 1 + 1 + 1
2 + 2 + 1                | Change 1's to 2's, then subtract 1. (2 + 2 + 2 - 1 = 2 + 2 + 1)
3 + 3                    | 3 + 3 + 1 - 1 = 3 + 3
4 + 3                    | 4 + 4 - 1 = 4 + 3
5 + 2                    | 5 + 3 - 1 = 5 + 2
6 + 1                    | 6 + 2 - 1 = 6 + 1
7                        | 7 + 1 - 1 = 7
7                        | 8 - 1 = 7
6                        | Numbers are now lower than the base, so just keep subtracting 1.
5                        |
4                        |
3                        |
2                        |
1                        |
0                        | End
```

Spacing doesn't matter.

---

### Winning criterion:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest code wins.

Comment: Is it required to include the last 0?

Comment: @KSab Hm.... no, I guess not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 19 bytes

```
Å1[D'+ý,N>D>:`Ž<)0K
```

Could also be rearranged as `` >Å1[ND>:`Ž<)0KD'+ý, ``

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cKthtIu69uG9On52LnZWCUf32mgaeP//bwwA)

**Explanation**

```
Å1                    # push a list of 1's the length of the input
  [                   # start a loop
   D                  # duplicate the current list
    '+ý,              # join on "+" and print
        N>D>:         # replace <current_iteration>+1 with <current_iteration>+2
             `        # flatten the list to the stack
              Ž       # break loop if the stack is empty
               <      # decrement the top number
                )     # wrap the stack in a list
                 0K   # remove zeroes
```

Answer (score 10):

## Python 2, <strike>77</strike> 74 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn)

```py
n=input();b=1
while n:print"+".join(n/b*[`b`]+[`n%b`][:n%b]);n+=n/b-1;b+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERD0zrJ1pCrPCMzJ1Uhz6qgKDOvRElbSS8rPzNPI08/SSs6ISkhVjs6IU8VSEdbAalYTes8bVugnK6hdZK2reH//8YA)

Easily runs up to n = 100 (though the output is too long for tio fully show).

Comment: "Spacing doesn't matter", so you're fine there.

Comment: Save a byte by reading input from STDIN: `n=input()` `b=1` `while n:…`

Comment: And two more with `n+=n/b-1;b+=1`. [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##DckxCoAgAAXQ3VOEEGhSYW2JJxFBhEIjvhJGdHpzesPLXwkJS63QEfkpjBOvJXlDvPYOW74jChV0OlMEw@wH47yzwjj0TbM1LFcQut0olRda1oOtvK4/)

Comment: TIO doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt fixed

Comment: Mind I ask why creating a manual newline works while using `;` doesn't?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt it apparently has to do with the while loop, you can't put a `while` following a `;`. I would guess that this is because if line is started with a `while` each following statement (seperated by semicolons) is considered inside its scope of the while and the behavior would be ambiguous or at least somewhat opaque

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 29 bytes

```
WQ=hZj\++*]Z/QZ<]J%QZJ=+Qt/QZ
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=WQ%3DhZj%5C%2B%2B%2a%5DZ%2FQZ%3C%5DJ%25QZJ%3D%2BQt%2FQZ&input=3&debug=0)**

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 123 bytes

```
(s=1~Table~#;i=1;While[s!={},Print@StringRiffle[ToString/@s,"+"];s=s/.i->i+1;s=Join[Most@s,{Last@s}-1]~DeleteCases~0;i++])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYmxCsIwFAB/pVYQJa01OIZIQSdREC04hAypvNgHbQO@bKX59RhxujtuML6DwXh8mWgzmcU1SR4a0/YQlgIlF88Oe1C0kNNc3D44@vrhE953tDaNxv2zqqnIWa4FSaq2WB6Q8eRnh6O6OvJpTxfz41xyHU7Qg4ejIaCwE8iY3qyiVXsdvw)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 155 bytes

```py
n=int(input());l=[1]*(n+1);i=0
while l:
    l=[t+1 if t==i else t for t in l];l[-1]-=1;l=l[:-1] if l[-1]==0 else l;print("+".join(list(map(str,l))));i+=1
```

This can be reformatted into

```py
n = int(input())
l = [0]*(n+1)
i = 0
while l:
    l = [t+1 if t==i else t for t in l]
    if l[-1] == 0:
        l = l[:-1]
    print("+".join(list(map(str,l))))
    i += 1
```

Comment: You miss the first line of `1+1+...`, and note that your program is supposed to handle any positive integer input.

Comment: corrected that -.- Should $n$ be read as input?

Comment: Yes please. Also, MathJax doesn't work on this site :P

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt noticed that :P corrected

Comment: Hm, you probably want to use `print(" + ".join(...)` to correspond with the output I require.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I put only "+" because you state spacing doesn't matter

Comment: For me, it appears you put a space in your golfed version instead of a `+`.

Comment: [106 bytes](https://tio.run/##JczBCsIwDIDhu08RdmpXK5bdrHmS0YPgZIGQhpkhXvbq3cTbf/j59GtzlaE1xjGVPm4k5kh0Ned9JryePjPxBHw7BgvOEMm/6gIGJMAl8xhTiZj@cU8PeQJftKrzWZef1vP5PSl2oTvAgKm1YQc)

Comment: @ovs what is that `-~` thing?

Comment: @RGS `-~x` has the same value as `x+1`, but you don't need to parenthesize it, as unary `-` (negation) and unary `~` (bitwise negation) do have a higher precedence than `*`. In your case `[1]*-~n` is equal to `[1]*(n+1)`.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript ES6, 121 chars

```
for(q=1,s=Array(+prompt()).fill(1).join`+`;s!=0;s=s.split(q).join(++q).replace(/\d+$/,x=>x-1).replace(/\+0$/,''))alert(s)
```

```js
alert=s=>document.write(s+'\n')
document.write("<pre>")

for(q=1,s=Array(+prompt()).fill(1).join`+`;s!=0;s=s.split(q).join(++q).replace(/\d+$/,x=>x-1).replace(/\+0$/,''))alert(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 71 bytes

```perl
$,='+';for(@a=(++$")x<>;@a;--$a[-1]||pop@a){say@a;$_+=$_==$"for@a;$"++}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19Fx1ZdW906Lb9IwyHRVkNbW0VJs8LGztoh0VpXVyUxWtcwtqamIL/AIVGzujixEiisEq9tqxJva6uiBNQE4itpa9f@/2/8L7@gJDM/r/i/rq@pnoGhAQA)