# Output the Goodstein sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence

(This might be quite classic but this is my first post here, so I'm not ready for the fancy stuff yet)

The [Goodstein sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoodsteinSequence.html) is defined for an input number as follows:

*Pick a starting number **n**, let **b**=2 and repeat:*

- *write **n** in heriditary base **b** notation*
- *substitute all the (**b**)s to (**b**+1)s in **n** and substract 1*
- *output the new decimal evaluation of **n***
- *increment **b***

Hereditary Base notation is a decomposition of a number where the basis is the bigger number to appear. Examples:

- `83` in HB3: `3^(3+1)+2`
- `226` in HB2: `2^(2^(2+1))+2^(2+1)+2`

Goodstein sequences [always end up at 0](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Goodstein%27s_theorem), but they tend to first get quite big quite fast so it is not asked to output the complete sequence.

---

**Task:**

Given an input number in any reasonable format, your job is to output the Goodstein sequence for this number at least until it reaches 10^25 or 0

**Examples:**

```
Input: 3
Output: 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0
Input: 13
Output: 13, 108, 1279, 16092, 280711, 5765998, 134219479, 3486786855, 100000003325, 3138428381103, 106993205384715, 3937376385706415, 155568095557821073, 6568408355712901455, 295147905179352838943, 14063084452067725006646, 708235345355337676376131, 37589973457545958193377292
Input: 38
Output: 38, 22876792454990
```

---

**Details:**

- Input number can be an array, a string, an integer, as long as it is in decimal base
- Output follows the same rule
- Separation of the terms in the output can be spaces, new-lines, or any reasonable separation
- As soon as the sequence becomes larger than 10^25, your program may exit normally, throw an error/exception, or continue (no restriction)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins
- Of course, [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden
- Python ungolfed working example [here](https://tio.run/##jVRNj5swEL3zK6ZaRUCaZje7t0hZqVV7bS@9pZHlwJC1CjYxZrf59enYOGBCWi0ne/zmzdcb6pN5UfLpfM5K3jTwhTe4joC@HAtgTEhhGEsaLIsF7Okx7V7tZ43LPWycPeqdeHuoUBrnM0V/3MAqCgJorLUPEIA1mlZLaIxOOr80iiLrkGOmqlo1mMj9KKEj5SH3njijSykak6TOgHR9cKe3F1EiYT@QYYh2XIAmyPH@3hIuifg46049JGu1hSR6AZj2VlGQ45jLmxGeoaMYP11xDeWgryYdwbF0XJvNe8ic/whA9Ete1yjzxOKGR@zmELSaoL7F@MrLlptJhykTc6qtOQXRgJBmMi8/gCvkoKkR1HfXlRjCTVuXt/Dbh92868J8HuS4Xe3C0id0VgdTYbVVsu1JhCeAQmkQVBlF210Ud0CJ2qIaw7XxvZDUcnd3N@tMBltn8pgGQpPwPBLHHdSa@pbEFgqzPIaZH2w6xfwy3vK9rfao1x4vB2gHDAxGn8YKySmtYGVuaSSI99UjhRFKUrzGxrM7mF/J0uV82fN/0tnr5w6E@f/obDf7YeSXYXzyAnVT/ZNhbeDHK@qiVG/ftFZ6fTvuT6Wg5PqAVqF4QFqMjEupDGRKGiFbjK@K0ch/07CF/R1JXiFjduFixiouJGNxF6jXweopjc7nvw)

Comment: Could you add an step-by-step of one test case?

Comment: ≥ 10²⁵ or > 10²⁵? Should that term be printed?

Comment: @Rod feel free to uncomment some lines in the linked TIO ;) tell me if that's enough or if you need more detail. Besides, I believe the YouTube Channel PBS Infinite Series has an excellent video on the topic

Comment: @user202729 you have to print all terms until the sequence reaches 10^25, so if one of the sequences were to contain that exact number, your program should print it too.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first challenge!

Comment: @tfbninja Thanks for the warm welcome

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/145628/8478) [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44453/8478)

Comment: In the 13 test case, I'm getting 295147905179352838943 instead of 295147905179352838671, and different results from then on. Looking at your numbers in the relevant bases, they then make less and less sense, so I think you have some kind of precision/overflow issue in the generating program.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Yeah, the bug is that `int(q/base.b), q%base.b` needs to be `q//base.b, q%base.b` (or simply `divmod(q, base.b)`) to avoid floating-point errors.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen & AndersKaseorg Thank you for pointing out this flaw in my example. I will edit the question/code and be more careful next time!

Comment: Does “at least until it reaches 10^25 or 0” mean the program is allowed to continue after it reaches 0 (presumably with −1, −2, −3, …)?

Comment: @AndersKaseorg it can continue after 0 even though it is not so interesting. The goal is to have the right terms until 0 or 10^25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>28</s> 26 bytes

```
.V2JbL&bs.e*^hJykb_jbJ=ty
```

The trailing newline is significant.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy/MyCvJRy2pWC9VKy7DqzI7KT4rycu2pJIr8P9/Q2MA) (This link includes an extra `Q` not needed by the current version of Pyth.)

#### How it works

```
.V2JbL&bs.e*^hJykb_jbJ=ty
.V2                          for b in [2, 3, 4, ...]:
   Jb                          assign J = b
     L                         def y(b):
      &b                         b and
                   jbJ             convert b to base J
                  _                reverse
         .e                        enumerated map for values b and indices k:
             hJ                      J + 1
            ^  yk                    to the power y(k)
           *     b                   times b
(newline)                      print Q (autoinitialized to the input)
                        y      y(Q)
                       t       subtract 1
                      =        assign back to Q
```

It’s important that `y` is redefined in each loop iteration to prevent memoization across changes to the global variable `J`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 77 bytes

`(&2)` is an anonymous function taking an `Integer` and returning a (potentially very long) list of `Integer`s, use as `(&2) 13`.

```hs
(&2)
n&b|n<0=[]|let _?0=0;e?n=(e+1)?div n b+mod n b*(b+1)^0?e=n:(0?n-1)&(b+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtLCsIwFAD3PUUWUl7UltQiiBqz8ALdKfgjta82mL5KU@3Gsxs/OJuBgam0u6K1vtaGpKEOW33uBneyhtDFtb5BwP7AnqKVq5oeaNzpK24qYxGWMhHHyZRDyYhzHreoi9/C475pCxeUcu8hnPCAwvxJSyF3h6fFjp2UkGKBiiTgKOGqMA9GLB/VTfH1EPJPPQqFkuYgFEUJD3/N@5QlKUtnr3Np9cX5aLvOsjc) (cuts off at `10^25`.)

## How it works

- `(&2)` starts the sequence with base `2`.
- `n&b` calculates the subsequence starting with the number `n` and base `b`.

  - It halts with an empty list if `n<0`, which generally happens the step after `n==0`.
  - Otherwise, it prepends `n` to the list returned recursively by the expression `(0?n-1)&(b+1)`.
- `?` is a local function operator. `0?n` gives the result of converting `n` to hereditary base `b`, then incrementing the base everywhere.

  - The conversion recurses with the variable `e` keeping track of the current exponent. `e?n` converts the number `n*b^e`.
  - The recursion halts with `0` when `n==0`.
  - Otherwise, it divides `n` by the base `b`.

    - `(e+1)?div n b` handles the recursion for the quotient and next higher exponent.
    - `mod n b*(b+1)^0?e` handles the remainder (which is the digit corresponding to the current exponent `e`), the increment of base, and converting the current exponent hereditarily with `0?e`.